# Oculus rviz plugins "No Oculus device found" - DK2, Ros Groovy

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the Oculus Rift DK2 working with rviz using oculus_rviz_plugins but, on Rviz, I always get the message '' No Oculus device found! ".

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Groovy, Oculus DK2.
After some googling, I suspect this issue happens because of the resolution. I am using DK2 so the only resolutions available are 1080x1920 and 1080x948. Should I be using 1280x800 (DK1) for the Oculus to work with rviz? manually setting it with xrandr does not seem to work...

This is the output I get when I try to run the Oculus Display Plugin on Rviz

OVR::DeviceManagerThread - running (ThreadId=0x7ff9b811c700).
OVR::DeviceManager - initialized.
OVR::DeviceManager - shutting down.
OVR::DeviceManagerThread - exiting (ThreadId=0x7ff9b811c700).

and on Rviz it just says:
'' No Oculus device found! ".

---

The OculusWorldDemo.sh example from the SDK works fine with video and perfect head tracking, only Rviz cant find it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193082/oculus-rviz-plugins-%22no-oculus-device-found%22---dk2,-ros-groovy/) by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jalfonso](https://answers.ros.org/users/15246/jalfonso/) on 2014-09-23**:
I get same message "No Oculus device found!" with Oculus Rift DK2 , Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro.

**Comment by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on 2014-09-24**:
Yeah I am pretty sure rviz_plugins simply does not support DK2. I am new to ros and rviz so I don't have the expertise, but I really want develop these patches for the dk2 to work on rviz. Anybody else willing to work on it? You guys think simply porting it to use the new oculus sdk might be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried things yet with our DK2 but given there have been significant API changes for it and there haven't been any updates to the [rviz plugin recently](https://github.com/ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins/), I'd expect things not to work until someone provides patches.

/edit: I created an issue on github to track any efforts for DK2 support: https://github.com/ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins/issues/19

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1